# Move multiple files with certain naming pattern from multiple folders using python

Tags: python, operating-system, move, file-management

I have folders like this

[image]

in each folder, it contains file like this :
[image]

i want to move every file with the name "Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-SPKU-Bulan*" in each folder to one designated folder, i try this code but nothing happened

```
target_folder = r"C:\Users\EVOSYS\Documents\PROJECT-ISPU-DKI-JAKARTA-main\File Gabungan ISPU di SPKU 2010 - 2021" + "\\"
source_folder = r"C:\Users\EVOSYS\Documents\PROJECT-ISPU-DKI-JAKARTA-main" + "\\"

for path, dir, files in os.walk(source_folder):
    if files:
        for file in files:
            if not os.path.isfile(target_folder + file):
                if "Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-SPKU-Bulan*" in file:
                    os.rename(path + '\\' + file, target_folder + file)
```

Comment: try this: `if "Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-SPKU-Bulan" in file:` - remove the asterisk

Comment: still didnt work